# linux command line subfolder files batch rename that actually works

Tags: linux, command, line, rename

In a folder with many subfolders, each containing mp4 files with names ending in foobar.mp4

How can I get rid of the suffix? I have tried:
`find ./*/*.mp4 -type f -exec rename 's/foobar//' '{}' \;`

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

On surface, there is no need to use 'find', as the rename command has the ability to process list of file. In particular, possible to write

```
rename 's/foobar//' */*foobar.mp4
```

It's not clear from the OP what are the actual file names. The above command will rename 'foobar.mp4' to `hidden` file '.mp4', and the file 'x.foobar.mp4' to 'x..mp4'.